# Power BI Calculate the percentage of a column based on one of the values in the column

Tags: powerbi

This is a very odd request.  It is difficult to explain in words, so let me show you what I am trying to do.  Lets say I have a table with the following values.

```
Category    Sales Qty    Current Year % Of Sales Compared to Helmets
Helmets        150                     150/150 = 100%
Gloves          70                      70/150 = 47%
Pants           80                      80/150 = 53%
```

I have tried doing this but it only works for the first row. The rest of the rows it will not calculate.

```
CY% =

    VAR _myPercent =
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Production[Sales]),
            FILTER(ALL(Production), Production[Category] = "Helmets"),
            FILTER(Production, Production[Week] <= Max(DatesTable[CurrentWeek])),
            FILTER(Production, Production[Year] = Max(DatesTable[CurrentYear]))
        )  
    Return
   
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Production[Sales]),
            FILTER(Production, Production[Week] <= Max(DatesTable[CurrentWeek])),
            FILTER(Production, Production[Year] = Max(DatesTable[CurrentYear]))
        )  
        /
        myPercent
```

Comment: Change everywhere in FILTER the first agument from `(Production)` to `ALL(Production)` this can help. If it works I'll explain why.

Comment: The calculation did work, but the filters no longer work for it.  Is there a way to make the filters work too?

Comment: try KEEPFILTERS() for [week]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working with your help.  I needed to add ALLSELECTED to each filter. Here is the final solution:

```
CY% =

    VAR _myPercent =
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Production[Sales]),
            FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Production), Production[Category] = "Helmets"),
            FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Production), Production[Week] <= Max(DatesTable[CurrentWeek])),
            FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Production), Production[Year] = Max(DatesTable[CurrentYear]))
        )  
    Return
   
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Production[Sales]),
            FILTER(Production, Production[Week] <= Max(DatesTable[CurrentWeek])),
            FILTER(Production, Production[Year] = Max(DatesTable[CurrentYear]))
        )  
        /
        _myPercent
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets check this code

```
CY% =

    VAR maxWeek = Max(DatesTable[CurrentWeek])
    VAR maxYear = Max(DatesTable[CurrentYear])


    VAR _myPercent =
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Production[Sales]),
            Production[Category] = "Helmets",
            KEEPFILTERS(Production[Week] <= maxWeek) ,
            Production[Year] = maxYear
        )  
    Return
   
        CALCULATE(
            SUM(Production[Sales]),
            KEEPFILTERS(Production[Week] <= maxWeek),
            Production[Year] = maxYear
        )  
        /
        myPercent
```

Comment: If you can add a screenshot of the visual with the result, then I'll try to find a solution.

Comment: It worked for helmets but the other values did not.  Thank you so much for trying to find a solution. I am sorry I cannot figure out how to attach a screen shot.  But here the results.  For Helmet it is 100%, for the other 2 categories it says infinity.

Comment: ok. I'll answer tomorow. Atthe first look it seems that there are no values for other. It can be that in your selected weeks there are no values for other goods.